# Why is qc() not respected inside a data.table without "with=FALSE" argument?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the `wrapr` package in R.
The function `qc()` is very useful to avoid typing of quotes several times e.g. when specifying column names. However a small irritant is that inside a R `data.table` we always need `with = FALSE` when trying to select column names with `qc()`. data.table documentation says `with=FALSE` will be deprecated soon. So what is a better way? See this example:

```
library(wrapr)
library(data.table)

x <- data.table(firstcol=1:3,secondcol=letters[1:3])
x[,"secondcol"] # works 
   secondcol
1:         a
2:         b
3:         c

x[,c("secondcol")] # works 
   secondcol
1:         a
2:         b
3:         c
```

But this does not work:

```
x[,qc(secondcol)] # does not work
#"secondcol"
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/tidyverse/glue?

Comment: I think it is being used incorrectly. `qc` uses `bquote` which will return a quoted string not the object itself. Maybe use `substitute` and the like?

Comment: `x[,qc(firstcol)]` doesn't seem to work either for me? returns "firstcol"

Comment: @BenBolker thanks to notice that. We now have a modified question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer after Edits**

This is to do with `data.table`'s unique subsetting(See `?special-symbols`). While one can use `with=FALSE`, this is as documented "no longer needed" and will likely be deprecated soon. We can instead do the following:

```
x[,.SD,.SDcols = qc(secondcol)]
   secondcol
1:         a
2:         b
3:         c
```

**Answer to [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57678725/2):**

If you look at the help documentation of `?qc`

> qc() a convenience function allowing the user to elide excess quotation marks. It quotes its arguments instead of evaluating them, except in the case of a nested call to qc() or c(). Please see the examples for typical uses both for named and un-named character vectors.
>
> qc() uses bquote() .() quasiquotation escaping notation.

it shows that `qc` uses `bquote` which will return the string not `eval`uated object. See for instance:
`qc(iris)`.

The above will return:

```
qc(iris)
[1] "iris"
```

Now, if we apply this to the question, using `-qc(iris)` will rightfully give the error:

> Error in -qc(iris) : invalid argument to unary operator

To solve this, we need to `eval`uate the argument. I would personally use `bquote` and other `base` alternatives:

```
x[,-eval(bquote(firstcol))]
[1]  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10

x[, qc(firstcol)]
#[1] "firstcol"
x[, -get(qc(firstcol))]
#[1]  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10
# using eval(substitute(...))
 x[,-eval(substitute(firstcol))] 
 [1]  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10
# tidyverse-like
 x[,-rlang::eval_tidy(firstcol)] 
[1]  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10
```

Comment: My apologies to all. The question begs a little change, And it turns out the `qc()` also worked in the changed scenario. The change `with=F` when inserted inside the data.table, the unary operator worked. I did discover glue and a host of other ways to be using text parsing and therefore thanks a lot to everyone. Shall I delete the question or modify it, because the problem does not exist with `with=F`

Comment: I think it's better to rollback to the previous question and add an answer that explains that it works with `with=FALSE`. I do note that the with=FALSE argumnent is stated as "no longer needed" in the `[.data.table` documentation.

Comment: I have modified the question to be closer to the problem now. ALso I have removed reference to "unary" because that was not the root problem.

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra I have edited the answer to show an alternative for the current question.